# how to get host from my hosting?

Tags: mysql, web-hosting

i am installing a mysql database for the very first time on my web hosting.
and am stuck. what value to put in $host in connection config of mysql DB?
the rest i know. till now i have been using localhost. now i am going live. from where to get the host information?

Comment: this isn't a programming question, use superuser.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only your provider knows.

It's likely to be localhost there as well, but you'll need user name and password from your provider even in that case.

Answer (score 2):

With all the web hosting providers I have used in the past, they have all used localhost, as opposed to an IP.

Comment: Yes, most do, but you should always check with them first.

Comment: Dreamhost.com, who I use, does not use localhost.

Answer (score 0):

Try the IP of the database server.  Should be able to get that from whatever hosting control panel they offer.